# It is possible to add an external CSS(also on SD card) file in a local web page built-in arduino sketch?

Tags: css, arduino

I am writing a code with arduino and ethernet shield. It consist in an accelerometer which reads values and shows them in a web page. It is in local. If I had to write CSS style with `client.print();` I would spend a lot of time and useless lines of code. I would like to add an external CSS sheet linked with the internal page made-up into the arduino sketch. I tried to put the CSSsheet into a directory of the sketch and set `<link href>` but it didn't work. The page is made like this:

@mike 
this is the whole function, thanks.

```
      void RichiesteAlServer() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.write(c);
        // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
        // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
        // so you can send a reply
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
          // send a standard http response header
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          //client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
          client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
          client.println();
          client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
          client.println("<html>");
          // output the value of each analog input pin
          client.println("<head><title>Sismografo</title><link href=\"css/style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\"/></head>");
          client.println("<body>");
          client.println("<h1>Sismografo</h1>");

          client.println("<p>");
          client.print("Indice Array : ");
          client.print(indiceArray);
          client.println("</p>");

          client.println("<p>");
          stampaCanvas(client);
          client.println("</p>");

          client.println("<p>");
          client.print("valore: ");
          client.print(arrayValoriAccel[indiceArray]);
          client.println("</p>");

          client.println("<p>");
          client.print("inizio scossa : ");
          client.print(inizio_scossa);
          client.println("</p>");


          client.println("<p>");
          client.print("fine scossa : ");
          client.print(fine_scossa);
          client.println("</p>");

          client.println("<p>");
          client.print("Durata scossa : ");
          client.print(durata_totale_scossa);
          client.println("</p>");

          client.println("<p>");
          client.print("cont : ");
          client.print(cont);
          client.println("</p>");

          client.println("</body>");
          client.println("</html>");



          break;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        } else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show you how tried, and how it didn't work. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: [edit] your question to provide more information.

Comment: You can post up to something like 30000 characters in a question... It's only comments that have the 500 character restriction. Like I said [edit] the question. You can click on the "edit" link below the tags on your question, or either of the links I've provided.

Comment: No need to @ mention me, this is for future readers. I've not worked with arduino, but it appears as though you're writing the entire HTTP response to the client, and don't actually have an HTTP server running on the chip. If that's the case, an external `link` is not going to work (since there's nothing there to respond). You'll likely have to read the CSS from the file and output it to the client line by line, within a `<style>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first question. I'm afraid you're right but I'll wait if someone has the solution. if not I'll write line by like as you said. thank you